# ListView color out of boundaries

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to find a simplest way how to override color which appears when you try to scroll ListView out of it's boundaries, if you know what I mean. I hope that this can be replaced by some simple way not involving 9 patch :). Thank you

Comment: EDIT : I`ve found one solution working for me android:overScrollMode="never", though this is only working for Android 2.3+

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `mListView.setCacheColorHint(color);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you were hoping for I know, but here's what I know of it:

```
<ListView
    android:overScrollHeader="@drawable/header"
    android:overScrollFooter="@drawable/footer"/>
```

or to do the same programatically with:

```
setOverscrollFooter(Drawable d);
setOverscrollHeader(Drawable d);
```